# Rails/Active Admin: redirections on update users reroot to localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I'm using Rails 5.1.4 with ActiveAdmin. The admin interface is basic and I haven't customized it a lot. It is used only to managed users on my website (reset passwords in case, ban, add etc.). Otherwise, users are managed by Devise.

I realised that in production, when I try to edit details of an user, I am redirected *after* the action to https://localhost/admin/users/1 instead of the production url. Adding a new user through the admin interface doesn't work either but I am not sure it is the same issue (just putting this fyi).

I am fairly new to rails and this is actually my first question on StackOverFlow.

Here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :users
  root to: 'pages#home'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  get 'my_points', to: 'points#user_points', as: :my_points

  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'

  resources :points do
    member do
      put "/is_featured", to: "points#featured", as: :featured
    end
    resources :reasons, only: [:new, :create]
  end
  resources :services
  resources :topics

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :topics, only: [ :index, :show ]
      resources :services, only: [ :index, :show ]
      resources :points, only: [ :index, :show ]
    end
  end
end
```

And my active_admin.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  # == Site Title
  #
  # Set the title that is displayed on the main layout
  # for each of the active admin pages.
  #
  config.site_title = "Phoenix"

  # Set the link url for the title. For example, to take
  # users to your main site. Defaults to no link.
  #
  # config.site_title_link = "/"

  # Set an optional image to be displayed for the header
  # instead of a string (overrides :site_title)
  #
  # Note: Aim for an image that's 21px high so it fits in the header.
  #
  config.site_title_image = "favicon.ico"

  # == Default Namespace
  #
  # Set the default namespace each administration resource
  # will be added to.
  #
  # eg:
  #   config.default_namespace = :hello_world
  #
  # This will create resources in the HelloWorld module and
  # will namespace routes to /hello_world/*
  #
  # To set no namespace by default, use:
  #   config.default_namespace = false
  #
  # Default:
  # config.default_namespace = :admin
  #
  # You can customize the settings for each namespace by using
  # a namespace block. For example, to change the site title
  # within a namespace:
  #
  #   config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  #     admin.site_title = "Custom Admin Title"
  #   end
  #
  # This will ONLY change the title for the admin section. Other
  # namespaces will continue to use the main "site_title" configuration.

  # == User Authentication
  #
  # Active Admin will automatically call an authentication
  # method in a before filter of all controller actions to
  # ensure that there is a currently logged in admin user.
  #
  # This setting changes the method which Active Admin calls
  # within the application controller.
  # config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!

  # == User Authorization
  #
  # Active Admin will automatically call an authorization
  # method in a before filter of all controller actions to
  # ensure that there is a user with proper rights. You can use
  # CanCanAdapter or make your own. Please refer to documentation.
  # config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::CanCanAdapter

  # In case you prefer Pundit over other solutions you can here pass
  # the name of default policy class. This policy will be used in every
  # case when Pundit is unable to find suitable policy.
  # config.pundit_default_policy = "MyDefaultPunditPolicy"

  # You can customize your CanCan Ability class name here.
  # config.cancan_ability_class = "Ability"

  # You can specify a method to be called on unauthorized access.
  # This is necessary in order to prevent a redirect loop which happens
  # because, by default, user gets redirected to Dashboard. If user
  # doesn't have access to Dashboard, he'll end up in a redirect loop.
  # Method provided here should be defined in application_controller.rb.
  # config.on_unauthorized_access = :access_denied

  # == Current User
  #
  # Active Admin will associate actions with the current
  # user performing them.
  #
  # This setting changes the method which Active Admin calls
  # (within the application controller) to return the currently logged in user.
  # config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user

  # == Logging Out
  #
  # Active Admin displays a logout link on each screen. These
  # settings configure the location and method used for the link.
  #
  # This setting changes the path where the link points to. If it's
  # a string, the strings is used as the path. If it's a Symbol, we
  # will call the method to return the path.
  #
  # Default:
  config.logout_link_path = :destroy_admin_user_session_path

  # This setting changes the http method used when rendering the
  # link. For example :get, :delete, :put, etc..
  #
  # Default:
  # config.logout_link_method = :get

  # == Root
  #
  # Set the action to call for the root path. You can set different
  # roots for each namespace.
  #
  # Default:
  # config.root_to = 'dashboard#index'

  # == Admin Comments
  #
  # This allows your users to comment on any resource registered with Active Admin.
  #
  # You can completely disable comments:
  # config.comments = false
  #
  # You can change the name under which comments are registered:
  # config.comments_registration_name = 'AdminComment'
  #
  # You can change the order for the comments and you can change the column
  # to be used for ordering:
  # config.comments_order = 'created_at ASC'
  #
  # You can disable the menu item for the comments index page:
  # config.comments_menu = false
  #
  # You can customize the comment menu:
  # config.comments_menu = { parent: 'Admin', priority: 1 }

  # == Batch Actions
  #
  # Enable and disable Batch Actions
  #
  config.batch_actions = true

  # == Controller Filters
  #
  # You can add before, after and around filters to all of your
  # Active Admin resources and pages from here.
  #
  # config.before_action :do_something_awesome

  # == Localize Date/Time Format
  #
  # Set the localize format to display dates and times.
  # To understand how to localize your app with I18n, read more at
  # https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib%2Fi18n%2Fbackend%2Fbase.rb#L52
  #
  config.localize_format = :long

  # == Setting a Favicon
  #
  config.favicon = 'favicon.ico'

  # == Meta Tags
  #
  # Add additional meta tags to the head element of active admin pages.
  #
  # Add tags to all pages logged in users see:
  #   config.meta_tags = { author: 'My Company' }

  # By default, sign up/sign in/recover password pages are excluded
  # from showing up in search engine results by adding a robots meta
  # tag. You can reset the hash of meta tags included in logged out
  # pages:
  #   config.meta_tags_for_logged_out_pages = {}

  # == Removing Breadcrumbs
  #
  # Breadcrumbs are enabled by default. You can customize them for individual
  # resources or you can disable them globally from here.
  #
  # config.breadcrumb = false

  # == Create Another Checkbox
  #
  # Create another checkbox is disabled by default. You can customize it for individual
  # resources or you can enable them globally from here.
  #
  # config.create_another = true

  # == Register Stylesheets & Javascripts
  #
  # We recommend using the built in Active Admin layout and loading
  # up your own stylesheets / javascripts to customize the look
  # and feel.
  #
  # To load a stylesheet:
  #   config.register_stylesheet 'my_stylesheet.css'
  #
  # You can provide an options hash for more control, which is passed along to stylesheet_link_tag():
  #   config.register_stylesheet 'my_print_stylesheet.css', media: :print
  #
  # To load a javascript file:
  #   config.register_javascript 'my_javascript.js'

  # == CSV options
  #
  # Set the CSV builder separator
  # config.csv_options = { col_sep: ';' }
  #
  # Force the use of quotes
  # config.csv_options = { force_quotes: true }

  # == Menu System
  #
  # You can add a navigation menu to be used in your application, or configure a provided menu
  #
  # To change the default utility navigation to show a link to your website & a logout btn
  #
  #   config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  #     admin.build_menu :utility_navigation do |menu|
  #       menu.add label: "My Great Website", url: "http://www.mygreatwebsite.com", html_options: { target: :blank }
  #       admin.add_logout_button_to_menu menu
  #     end
  #   end
  #
  # If you wanted to add a static menu item to the default menu provided:
  #
  #   config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  #     admin.build_menu :default do |menu|
  #       menu.add label: "My Great Website", url: "http://www.mygreatwebsite.com", html_options: { target: :blank }
  #     end
  #   end

  # == Download Links
  #
  # You can disable download links on resource listing pages,
  # or customize the formats shown per namespace/globally
  #
  # To disable/customize for the :admin namespace:
  #
  #   config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  #
  #     # Disable the links entirely
  #     admin.download_links = false
  #
  #     # Only show XML & PDF options
  #     admin.download_links = [:xml, :pdf]
  #
  #     # Enable/disable the links based on block
  #     #   (for example, with cancan)
  #     admin.download_links = proc { can?(:view_download_links) }
  #
  #   end

  # == Pagination
  #
  # Pagination is enabled by default for all resources.
  # You can control the default per page count for all resources here.
  #
  # config.default_per_page = 30
  #
  # You can control the max per page count too.
  #
  # config.max_per_page = 10_000

  # == Filters
  #
  # By default the index screen includes a "Filters" sidebar on the right
  # hand side with a filter for each attribute of the registered model.
  # You can enable or disable them for all resources here.
  #
  # config.filters = true
  #
  # By default the filters include associations in a select, which means
  # that every record will be loaded for each association.
  # You can enabled or disable the inclusion
  # of those filters by default here.
  #
  # config.include_default_association_filters = true

  # == Footer
  #
  # By default, the footer shows the current Active Admin version. You can
  # override the content of the footer here.
  #
  # config.footer = 'my custom footer text'

  # == Sorting
  #
  # By default ActiveAdmin::OrderClause is used for sorting logic
  # You can inherit it with own class and inject it for all resources
  #
  # config.order_clause = MyOrderClause
  def authenticate_admin!
    redirect_to new_user_session_path unless current_user && current_user.admin
  end

  ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
    config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin!
    config.current_user_method = :current_user
    config.logout_link_path = :destroy_user_session_path
    config.logout_link_method = :delete
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Edit: adding production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method     = :postmark
  config.action_mailer.postmark_settings   = { api_key: ENV['POSTMARK_API_KEY'] }
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "phoenix.tosdr.org" }

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Attempt to read encrypted secrets from `config/secrets.yml.enc`.
  # Requires an encryption key in `ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]` or
  # `config/secrets.yml.key`.
  config.read_encrypted_secrets = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "phoenix_#{Rails.env}"
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  # Enforce SSL in production
  config.force_ssl = true

end
```

Comment: Could you copy/paste your config/environements/production.rb please ?

Also did you check that you do not have an hard call to `localhost` in the code where it is not required ?

Comment: I added it to the original question :)